# ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

Tags: sql, oracle

Maybe I am putting the parenthesis wrong or a wrong comma? I know this is a fairly novice question so I apologize in advance. I originally had this code:

```
es3.last_name || ', ' ||SUBSTR(es3.first_name,1,1)
```

But es3 was a Left Outer Join so all the blanks were showing the ', ' so I tried this below and am getting the ERROR

> ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

```
NVL(es3.last_name, ' ' , es3.last_name || ', ' ||SUBSTR(es3.first_name,1,1))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The syntax for the NVL function in Oracle/PLSQL is:
>
> `NVL( string1, replace_with )`

You are feeding it 3 arguments, hence the error message.  I believe you want this instead:

```
CASE WHEN es3.last_name IS NULL
     THEN ''
     ELSE es3.last_name || ', ' ||SUBSTR(es3.first_name,1,1)
END
```

Comment: Thank you Aaron this did the trick! I didn't even consider a CASE. I tried to up vote but my rep is too low:( Thank you for the help and to everyone else!

Answer (score 3):

NVL can have only two arguments

```
NVL(String, Value )
```

So the above function will return 'Value' when string is null. And 'String' itself when string is not null.

Use NVL2. NVL2 can have three arguments

```
NVL2(String, Value_when_not_null, Value_When_Null)
```

So when 'String' is not null, it returns second parameter. When String is null it returns third paramater.

So your function should be

```
NVL2(es3.last_name||es3.first_name , es3.last_name||','||es3.first_name, ' ')
```

Comment: It seems to still be bringing back the commas in the null ones...I appreciate your help though, thank you! Is it because the comma quote is on its own?

Comment: Its not because of comma. You have to use NVL2 instead of NVL for your case.

Answer (score 2):

you must have only two arguments for

> nvl function

like in `NVL(es3.last_name,'Özhan')` returns `Özhan` if `es3.last_name` is null.

i.e. problem stems from having more than two arguments.

In the question problematic part is ..`' ' ,`.. in

> NVL(es3.last_name, `' ' ,` es3.last_name || ', '
>   ||SUBSTR(es3.first_name,1,1))